# Composer commands generate error on Windows 8 and Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php

I am trying to run the command `composer install` from the command line and every time I do so I generate the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
ssage":"main(): Failed opening required '..\/app\/controllers\/UsersController.p
hp' (include_path='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\html\\vendor\/phpseclib\/phpsecli
b\/phpseclib;.;C:\\xampp\\php\\PEAR')","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\html\
\app\\filters.php","line":2}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post
-install-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p
lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress
] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [pac
kages1] ... [packagesN]
```

I also get the exact same error when running:

```
composer update
```

I am on Windows 8, using XAMPP, the PHP version is 5.5, and I am using Laravel 4. It is also worth noting that I copied this project from a Git repository and not create a project from scratch.

And I get the following response when trying to run the command `php composer.phar update`

```
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

Thank you in advance! I am new to Laravel so feel free to spell things out for me, I might need it.

Comment: It seems there is an error in your app/filters.php file from the message you posted. 
For the `Could not open input file: composer.phar` error, if you have installed composer globally then just use `composer` and the command you want to use. If not then it seems that windows can not find the file in the directory from which you are running this command

Comment: I think you may have one of the three issues 1) you have permissions error to your laravel installation folder or your composer.phar file is not located where it should be or your PATH is not set correctly